# A way to looping through all the individual credentials in a file and when it finds a match it gives you access to log in

Tags: c++

I wrote a code that creates a file to store personal credentials like name, marital status, password and account number, more like personal Deets for login authentication and more like a banking record taking in a file and then you can use the account number and password to login. But the problem is it can accept all different user credentials and append it to the file but when logging in, it only reads the first credential and as a result other users can't log in.

I have this for reading the file;

```cpp
ifstream InputFile;
InputFile.open("record.txt", std::ios_base::in);

cout << endl << endl << "Enter Account Number to Login" << endl << endl;
cin >> ACN;

cout << endl << endl << "Enter Password to login" << endl << endl;
cin >> Pass_word;

if (InputFile >> Account_Number && InputFile >> Password && Account_Number == ACN && Password == Pass_word) {
    cout << endl << "Welcome Back" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << endl << "Login Error, Please Create Account or check credentials" << endl;
}

InputFile.close();
```

The file input is

```
ofstream RecordFile;
RecordFile.open("record.txt",  std::ios_base::app);
ofstream User_Credentials;
User_Credentials.open("credentials.txt");
```

Then I take credentials

The Code up there is what i tried. I really thought this was gon work.

Comment: `while (/* read a record */) { /* process a record */ }` is the general way to do something like this.

Comment: Which string types do you use? Make sure that == can be used for comparisons.

Comment: And since you'll probably do this more than once, read the file into records as in above comment and then store the records in a `std::vector` or other container that better fits your needs.

Comment: Assuming these fields are all strings, if the user enters information that contains whitespace, you're gonna have problems. If you want to store multiple records in the file, you'll need _some_ kind of format. Yours doesn't seem to have any. I'm sure this is just a toy project for learning, but it should be pointed out that storing passwords as plaintext is generally considered evil and dangerous.

Comment: [And so are many of the naiive alternatives](https://xkcd.com/1286/)